# LatexDiff is gettign error while processing Tabu tag

Tags: pdftex, latexdiff

I am using latexdiff to generate difference between two file. After executing the following code I have created the new main.tex file.

`latexdiff   --exclude-textcmd="section,subsection"  mainold.tex mainnew.tex > main.tex`

Now, I am facing an error related to table tag while compiling the main.tex file. Error is :

````
\bottomrule ->\noalign 
                       {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \@aboverulesep =\aboverulesep \global...
l.1751 \end{tabu}```

I am wondering is there any way to solve this? or any way to ignore drawing the difference of the table? Instead just keep the old table, mark that as red. and add the new table in the difference file.

Any suggestion or help is welcome.
````

Comment: Does something like https://yezhang2012.wordpress.com/2016/10/17/latexdiff-tips/ help? You would probably have to add `tabu` as in --`config="PICTUREENV=(?:picture|DIFnomarkup|align|tabular|tabu)[\w\d*@]*"`

Comment: Should I execute the following command - `latexdiff  --config="PICTUREENV=(?:picture|DIFnomarkup|align|tabular|tabu)[\w\d*@]*"  --exclude-textcmd="section,subsection"  mainold.tex mainnew.tex > main.tex`

?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have commented out all the tables and figures before executing latexdiff. After generating the diff file, I put my figures and tables there. It works for me.